# subprocess.check_output: threading.lock.acquire(block, timeout) never returns if timeout is set

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, subprocess

I have a locking process I need to escape from, so I set a timeout, but it still hangs forever. This is windows10 and python3.10.2, shell=True|False do nothing

I do a keyboardInterrupt after 30+ seconds:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\dist\work\rancher\bin\ranchercli.py", line 87, in <module>
    dat = tools.exe.psexe(f"{ranchercli},context,switch".split(','), returnjson=False, shell=shell, timer=3)
  File "c:\dist\work\rancher\tools\exe.py", line 51, in psexe
    out = subprocess.check_output(shell_exe, shell=shell, timeout=timer)
  File "C:\dist\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 420, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "C:\dist\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    exc.stdout, exc.stderr = process.communicate()
  File "C:\dist\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1149, in communicate
    stdout, stderr = self._communicate(input, endtime, timeout)
  File "C:\dist\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1523, in _communicate
    self.stdout_thread.join(self._remaining_time(endtime))
  File "C:\dist\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1089, in join
    self._wait_for_tstate_lock()
  File "C:\dist\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1109, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
    if lock.acquire(block, timeout):
KeyboardInterrupt
```

From python310\lib\threading.py this function never returns, can it be something blocking. Really appreciate some tips on how to debug this. How can I check the thread states?

```
    def _wait_for_tstate_lock(self, block=True, timeout=-1):
        # Issue #18808: wait for the thread state to be gone.
        # At the end of the thread's life, after all knowledge of the thread
        # is removed from C data structures, C code releases our _tstate_lock.
        # This method passes its arguments to _tstate_lock.acquire().
        # If the lock is acquired, the C code is done, and self._stop() is
        # called.  That sets ._is_stopped to True, and ._tstate_lock to None.
        lock = self._tstate_lock
        if lock is None:
            # already determined that the C code is done
            assert self._is_stopped
            return

        try:
            if lock.acquire(block, timeout):
                lock.release()
                self._stop()
        except:
            if lock.locked():
                # bpo-45274: lock.acquire() acquired the lock, but the function
                # was interrupted with an exception before reaching the
                # lock.release(). It can happen if a signal handler raises an
                # exception, like CTRL+C which raises KeyboardInterrupt.
                lock.release()
                self._stop()
            raise
```

Comment: It should timoute but hangs forever. Only happens on windows, linux and kubernetes console is fine. Nice to know what can block `lock.acquire(block, timeout)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the timeout is not forwarded in this line:

> ```
>   File "C:\dist\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 512, in run
>     exc.stdout, exc.stderr = process.communicate()
> ```

This is a bug that has not been fixed on Windows:

- [proc communicate not exiting on python subprocess timeout using PIPES — python/cpython#75628](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/75628)
- [subprocess.check_output() with timeout does not exit if child process does not generate output after timeout — python/cpython#76976](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/76976)

The workaround is to force a default timeout:

```py
from functools import partial

subprocess.Popen.communicate = partial(subprocess.Popen.communicate, timeout=30)
```